# R sink() to database

Tags: database, r, sink

[`sink()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/sink.html) is useful for logging errors to file without having to wrap everything in `tryCatch`'s. However, instead of logging to a file, I would like to log to a (SQLite) database table. Is this possible?

More generally, with `sink()`, how can I specify my own function to handle the actual write process?

Comment: Why go out of your way to avoid using the right tools? There's a specific package designed to talk to SQLite db's. Use that to write your own logging function. Why insist on using sink (which isn't even a generic function)?

Comment: @joran I want to use `sink` because it automatically logs errors/warnings, no matter if they are handled or not. Sure, I could write my own logging function, but then I would have to wrap all my calls in `tryCatch`, i.e. `tryCatch(dodgyFunc(), error = myLoggingFunc)`

Comment: Making `sink` talk to a SQLite db is going to be **way** more work than simply writing your own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sink` diverts to a `connection`, not a file. To sink to a DB table, you simply need to use a  connection that writes to a database table instead.

```
dbc = dbconnection(host="mysql.example.com", table="logs",field="logtext")
```

This then opens a database connection to the host. Then you do:

```
sink(dbc)
print("stuff")
sink()
```

Then the database connection code does INSERT INTO logs (time,logtext) VALUES ("12-Jan-2001" "R output comes here") - if you want to do datestamped log entries, for example.

So all you need to do is write that function that creates a `connection` to the database. Which I think has to be done at the C level - I don't know if you can create new connection types in pure R. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `capture.output()`. It allows you to save the output of a given command(s) to variable and do whatever you want with it:

```
out <- capture.output({
    i <- 1
    cat(i, "\n")
    cat(i+1, "\n")
})
```

You can then use `out` variable for storing into database, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use write.csv(df,file = "~/df.csv",append=TRUE), to put the data frame *df* out as a .csv which I think matches your needs (since most software reads .csv). Append places your new info at the end of an existing .csv, otherwise it will *replace* the file.

```
messups<-warnings()
write.csv(messups,file = "~/messups.csv",append=TRUE)
```